# time efficient way to loop over nested dictionary in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

i have one nested dictionary, sample is `dict = {'exp_0': {'A':obj, 'B':obj}, 'exp_1': {'A': obj, 'C':obj, 'D':obj}, 'exp_2': {'E':obj, 'C': obj, 'F':obj}}`

The obj is the object of a class, i need to call a function of obj for each and every element. so i wrote below piece of code

```
for expr in dict:
    for k, v in dict[expr].items():
        v.somefunction() ## some function is in obj class

def somefunction():
    # this class has self.id variable
    inst = {"a": self.a, "b":self.b}
    try:
        with open("test", "w") as ffile:
            json.dump(inst, ffile)
        print("success for %s" %(self.id))
    except:
        print("Failre for %s" %(self.id))
```

This code is working fine, the problem is, it's taking a huge lot of time, let's say if nested dictionary   `{'A': obj, 'B': obj, ...}` has 500 elements, then it is taking `8-9 seconds`

Is there any time efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The time probably is not taken by dictionary iteration. The actual time might be due to opening and closing of files multiple times in the for loop and doing `json.dump()` also in for loop. Since `somefunction()` is getting called from inside nested loop.

You should rather collect your data in an intermediate collection. Then open the file once, write list of values, and then close the file at the end (again, only once). It should improve the performance.

Multiple calls to `json.dump()` could also be an issue.

In these cases, it's always better to transform your code to perform operation in bulk. That would get you perf improvement.

Comment: If he needs to write a new file for each object, how can he only open a file once?

Comment: If he has to write new file for each object, then there is not much one can do. Only thing is to parallelize the process.

Comment: @RoadRunner yes, you are correct, i need to dump in a new file for each object.

Comment: @ggupta And why would you need to do that? Probably let us know the problem. May be there could be better solution.

Comment: @RohitJain, the whole case is object is of a container class ,let's say a window. for every element like 'A', 'B', they have a separate container. so i need to dump the instance variable (not all) of each element container to new file. PS: pickle is not an option for me.

Comment: @ggupta I don't think you can do much, if you really need to write them to separate file. Still you can try to profile your code, and see which part of your code is taking the most time. Use `cProfile`, get the stats, and convert to graph (using `graphviz`).

Comment: @RohitJain thanks for suggestion, i think i should profile my code